# Standard Deviation of a Ratio of Two Numbers with Different Standard Deviations but High Correlation?

Tags: standard-deviation

I have two means that are highly correlated (R = 0.83) with normal distributions but with different standard deviations. When I divide the two means to get a ratio, how do I calculate the standard deviation of this ratio?

Comment: The details matter.  In particular, the standard deviation is infinite; but if you wish a practical approximation under the assumption that the denominator has vanishing chance of equaling zero, then the "delta method" works pretty well (it's the first method given in the Wikipedia reference in Andreas Steimer's answer).

Answer (score 1):

The different cases of ratio distributions based on gaussians can be found here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Correlated_noncentral_normal_ratio